# Trying to execute a function in the constructor

Tags: php

The point is to execute a function in the constructor, like this for example.

```
$clas = new andrestest();

class andrestest{

   function __construct(){
     FunctionName(); 
   }

   public function FunctionName()
   {
     echo 10;
   }

}
```

Comment: Your'e not trying to execute a global function; you're trying to execute a class method for this instance: `function __construct(){
     $this->FunctionName(); 
   }`

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things

```
   function __construct(){
     $this->FunctionName(); 
   }
```

or

```
   function __construct(){
     self::FunctionName(); 
   }
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `self::FunctionName()` applies to static methods and `$this->FunctionName();` to instance methods

Comment: thank you i though that this was applied onli for variables thx alote, but why i got 2 down arrows on may ask?